# Working with 2 apps android

Tags: android, android-intent, qr-code, zxing

I'm working with android and I have a question. How I can do if I am doing an app that need another app. For example one of my option needs an app that reads code QR (2D) how can I work with both?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should be integrating via intent. See here for details how: https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent.

By doing it this way you eliminate the need to try to copy the barcode scanner app into your own which I think you'll find to be somewhat difficult(Not to mention you won't be tasked with trying to maintain a project that is not yours as new verions of the OS are released). You'll also be saving your users the space of *another* copy of the barcode scanner application.

Integrating via intent is the way that the authors of barcode scanner intended for you to use it along with your own application.